# how to check if an argument is an integer and if not return nil

Tags: ruby, methods, null, integer

how would I write this in ruby " check if something is an integer, if not return nil. otherwise divide it by 2 and return the result. I
don't understand how to get it to check if it's not an integer and return nil. to write it in a function
`def halve(x)  x / 2  end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, you can use [`instance_of?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_of-3F) to check if the object is an instance of a given class and [`is_a?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) which returns `true` if the given class is the class of the object, or if the given class is one of the superclasses of the object.

In Ruby polymorphism or duck-typing is preferred, in this example, I would argue that one of those methods is a great choice too. IMHO `is_a?` is more idiomatic than `instance_of?` in Ruby but that depends on your specific use case.

```
def halve(x)
  if x.is_a?(Integer)
    x / 2.0  
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Note that I change `x / 2` to `x / 2.0` because imagine `x = 3` then `x / 2` would return `1` but `x / 2.0` will return `1.5`. See the docs of [`Integer#/`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-2F) for details.

Comment: Actually, "is an integer" is a much more tricky question in Ruby. Arguably, at least to me, "is an integer" is *not* `is_a?(Integer)` but rather `responds_to?(:to_int)`.

Comment: I think the OP wants a truncated integer division. What's the point of first restricting yourself to `Integer` values, and then return a `Float`? Perhaps a somewhat more meaningful alternative would be a `Rational`, but since we don't know the exact use case, we can only guees.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : I like your idea, but you are aware that your approach would allow to to divide `nil` by 2?

Comment: @user1934428: How would that allow to divide `nil` by 2? `nil` is not an integer and therefore does not respond to `to_int`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : I tried in the Cygwin port of Ruby (2.6.4) in irb `nil.to_i` and got 0 as result. I have another Ruby hanging around (jruby 1.7.27) where `NilClass` does **not** have a `to_int`. I guess this (IMHO questionable) feature sneaked into Ruby at some time ...

Comment: @user1934428 JörgWMIttag suggested testing if the object responds to `to_int`, not to `to_i`.

Comment: @user1934428: I still don't understand what you are talking about. `NilClass` *never* had a `to_int` method. It wouldn't make sense for it to have one.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! I understood what it was asking but couldn't for the life of me figure out how to write it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag:  I just checked the irb on my Mac, which has Ruby 2.6.3, and here too, `nil.to_i` works. I  tested it by doing a `ruby -e 'puts nil.to_i'`, which outputs 0. May I ask you which Ruby version you are using for testing this?

Comment: @user1934428 I am confused. When did `to_i` enter the discussion? I was only ever talking about `to_int`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : You are right! My misreading. I was not aware that we have `to_int` along with `to_i`!

Answer (score 0):

```rb
def halve(x)
  x.is_a?(Integer) ? x.fdiv(2) : nil
end
```

`#is_a?(obj)` returns true if the argument passed is the class of that object. You can also use `#kind_of?(obj)`.

`#fdiv(n)` returns float. `1.fdiv(2)` will return 0.5 (might be what you want) unlike `1 / 2` which returns 0.